# RPi & VisualGDB - running GUI application

Tags: debug

I am trying to run an application compiled in VisualGDB on my Raspberry Pi. In Visual Studio debugging works fine, but I need to run this application on an HDMI monitor. I tried to run the file on RPi, changing the directory to "Project\Debug" and using the command "./MyApp" but it says "MyApp: cannot connect to X server". I am using Raspbian Lite. Since I am an ultra beginner and not really familiar with Linux I don't know how to deal with this problem.

Comment: Did you follow this sample tutorial? https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/qt5/

Comment: Yes, but this example shows how to debug the application in Visual Studio - there is nothing about how to run it using a HDMI monitor connected to the Raspberry

Comment: sounds like you should run your app on Raspberry (so it would be started in local window - displayed on HDMI screen - and not tunneled to x-window emulator on your Windows machine) and then attach remotely via VS/VisualGDB. Please see if this tutorial https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/linux/attach/ will help you.

Comment: I am trying to fallow this tutorial, but when I type "sudo apt-get build-dep mc" and "apt-get source mc", I get "E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list". I opened the file using "sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list" and there are 3 lines: 1. deb http:raspbian.raspberrypi.org... 2. #uncoment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source' 3. #deb-src http:/raspbian.raspberrypi.org... - What should I add here to be able to use commands "sudo apt-get build-dep mc" and "apt-get source mc"?

Comment: that's just a sample source code for demonstration purposes (they used Midnight Commander sources to do that). So just skip this part and substitute it with your program source code.